# SQL selecting distinct rows by date

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

I have a table called `CLOCK` with 2 columns `ID` which is a NUMBER and `CLOCK_IN` which is a date. The `ID` column has repeated number, I want to select IDs that have the newest `CLOCK_IN`.

Like say the table has the following data:

```
+--+---------+
|ID|CLOCK_IN |
+--+---------+
|02|1/14/2013|
+--+---------+
|04|1/14/2013|
+--+---------+
|02|1/20/2013|
+--+---------+
|03|2/13/2013|
+--+---------+
```

I would want to get row 2,3,4 since they are they newest clock_ins for that ID.

Comment: Yes i have tried. I only need to select the ID i don't need the CLOCK_IN. I tried SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM CLOCK
ORDER BY CLOCK_IN but this errors.

Comment: In your attempt,you have selected distinct 'id's but tried to order with a different entity, can this be practically possible? Actually SQL is how you think more than just coding..!! Just my thoughts..

Comment: Always post what you've tried, and what the result was. That way people don't think you're just trying to get others to do your work for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ID, MAX(CLOCKIN)
FROM CLOCK
GROUP BY ID
```

Note that your column `ID` can't be the PRIMARY KEY alone (on your data example), I guess the two columns compounds the PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 3):

group by and max should work for you.

```
SELECT ID, MAX(CLOCK_IN)
FROM CLOCK
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  Clock_IN ASC) AS RN,ID,Clock_IN
 From Clock 
) AS Temp
WHERE RN = 1
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Vignesh, isn't it `CLOCKIN DESC` ?